# Extruding a circle along a curve resulting in a flat end at one end

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

So I extruded the circle along the line but every time it ends up with a flat end. The start is fine but I can't get it to stay circular.

[image: text]

Comment: maybe make sure that the vertices radius of your curve are at 1, or please share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pWS2gsO0Dq1NLQh-ysXwmNbRMeBWmUhz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Open your *N* panel and see the *Transform values*, your curve is scaled at 0.045 on X, so you need to apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), also once applied, switch to *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and right click >  *Set Curve Radius* > 1 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>